# Finding co-ordinates inside an imageview?

Tags: android, imageview, coordinates

Im trying to find the co-ordinates were a user is touching inside an imageview only.

So far i have managed to do this by the following code:

```
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    img.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            x = (int) event.getX();
            y = (int) event.getY();
            int[] viewCoords = new int[2];
            img.getLocationOnScreen(viewCoords);
            int imageX = (int) (x - viewCoords[0]); // viewCoods[0] is the X coordinate
            int imageY = (int) (y - viewCoords[1]); // viewCoods[1] is the y coordinate
            text.setText("x:" +x +"y"+y);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

However this is onTouchListener which means it only finds the co-ordinates after each touch, what i want to do is create it so that it constantly finds co-ordinates while the user moves their finger around the imageview. I achieved this for the whole screen by this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    x = (float)event.getX();
    y = (float)event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    }



    text.setText("x:"+ x +" y:" +y);

return false;
}
```

However I don't know how to make this code work inside the imageview only.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you `return false` at the end of the onTouch event.

When you `return false`, you are telling the OS that you are no longer interested in any events related to this particular gesture, so it stops informing your view of future activity (such as ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP).

Return `true` to `onTouchEvent`, and you will continue to receive a stream of events as long as the finger is held to the screen, and a final event when it is released.

Comment: Thanks so much! so simple yet you saved me alot of time there.